# Trying to simplify assigning characters to numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to assign characters to values in the minimal amount of lines possible

This is all I know how to do. I looked at other solutions but can't seem to get them to work

```
letter = random.randint(1,26)
if letter == 1:
    actualLetter = "A"
elif letter == 2:
    actualLetter = "B"
elif letter == 3:
    actualLetter = "C"
elif letter == 4:
    actualLetter = "D"
elif letter == 5:
    actualLetter = "E"
elif letter == 6:
    actualLetter = "F"
elif letter == 7:
    actualLetter = "G"
elif letter == 8:
    actualLetter = "H"
elif letter == 9:
    actualLetter = "I"
elif letter == 10:
    actualLetter = "J"
elif letter == 11:
    actualLetter = "K"
elif letter == 12:
    actualLetter = "L"
elif letter == 13:
    actualLetter = "M"
elif letter == 14:
    actualLetter = "N"
elif letter == 15:
    actualLetter = "O"
elif letter == 16:
    actualLetter = "P"
elif letter == 17:
    actualLetter = "Q"
elif letter == 18:
    actualLetter = "R"
elif letter == 19:
    actualLetter = "S"
elif letter == 20:
    actualLetter = "T"
elif letter == 21:
    actualLetter = "U"
elif letter == 22:
    actualLetter = "V"
elif letter == 23:
    actualLetter = "W"
elif letter == 24:
    actualLetter = "X"
elif letter == 25:
    actualLetter = "Y"
elif letter == 26:
    actualLetter = "Z"
```

`actualLetter` is assigned the letter corresponding to the value.

Comment: What other solutions? What specific problem made them not work? Why not use the value as an index, or just `random.choice` from a string (e.g. `string.ascii_uppercase`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `string.ascii_uppercase`:

```
import random
from string import ascii_uppercase:

letter = random.randint(1, 26)
actualLetter = ascii_uppercase[letter - 1]
```

Even better, use `random.choice` (the preferable solution):

```
actualLetter = random.choice(ascii_uppercase)
```

Or, without `string.ascii_uppercase`:

```
letter = random.randint(1, 26)
actualLetter = chr(letter + ord('A') - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just rely on the built in ascii mapping, using 'ord()' and 'chr()'

In [8]: ord('A')
Out[8]: 65

In [9]: chr(65)
Out[9]: 'A'